# Approximation of binomial using Poisson random variable

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

In the book "Introduction to probability and statistics for engineers", I found one explanation for how Poisson random variable can be used to approximate the binomial distribution, it goes like this:

> Suppose that X is a binomial random variable with parameters (n, p) and let λ = np, then

$$
\begin{align*}
P\{X =i\} &= \frac{n!}{(n - 1)! i!} p^{i} (1 - p)^{n - i}
\\&= \frac{n!}{(n - 1)! i!}(\frac{\lambda }{n})^{i}(1 - \frac{\lambda }{n})^{n - i}
\\&= \frac{n(n-1)...(n-i+1)}{n^{i}}\frac{\lambda^{i} }{n!}\frac{(1 - \lambda/n)^{n}}{(1 - \lambda/n)^{i}}
\end{align*}
$$

> Now, for n large and p small,

$$
\begin{align*}
&(1 - \frac{\lambda }{n})^{n} \approx e^{\lambda} &&& \frac{n(n-1)...(n-i+1)}{n^{i}} \approx 1 &&&& (1 - \frac{\lambda }{n})^{i} \approx 1&
\end{align*}
$$

> Then:

$$
P\{X = i\} \approx e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}
$$

What I don't understand is this approximation:

$$
\frac{n(n-1)...(n-i+1)}{n^{i}} \approx 1
$$

My understand is that if $i$ is also large enough, let's say $i \approx n$ then the LHS express will approximate to $0$ instead of $1$?

Comment: In this approximation $i$ and $\lambda$ are both fixed while $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan There's no mentioning of such condition, also since X is a binomial random variable with parameters (n, p), $i$ can be any value ranging from $0$ to $n$ right?

Comment: They're being sloppy. But I'm telling you what the domain of validity of the approximation is: $i$ and $\lambda$ are both fixed and $n \to \infty$ is large. If you don't assume this then you don't get the approximation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Agree 100%, thanks for our help!

Comment: This is known as the Poisson limit theorem; see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595961/poisson-limit-theorem-random-variable-x-n-binn-p-n-convergences-to-z/4594828#4594828

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-i+1)}{n^{i}} =\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{n^i\,\Gamma (n+1-i)}$$

Take logarithms and use Stirling approximation for $n \gg i$ to obtain
$$\log(A)=-\frac{(i-1) i}{2 n}-\frac{(i-1) i (2 i-1)}{12
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ So, $\log(A) \to 0^-$ and then $A \to 1^-$.

Comment: I can understand the approximation when $n >> i$ but in this case $i$ can be any value from 0 to n, there's no mentioning of such limiting condition.